# How to get the physical address of the associated data from a struct page?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

Let's say we've got a `struct page` from the address space of a page cached file.

How could we get the starting physical address of the 4KB data from this `struct page`?

I suppose there should be something like the `data` pointer inside `struct sk_buff`, but I didn't find it.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks Mat and llya for the answers.

After looking at the answers, I think the first problem is to identify whether the `struct page` is located in `ZONE_NORMAL` or `ZONE_HIGHMEM`.

During a file I/O, when we don't find the cached page, we will at first allocate a new page using `page_cache_alloc_cold()`. `page_cache_alloc_cold()` will finally calls `alloc_pages()` which looks like it will use the `ZONE_HIGHMEM` (which in x86, is the kernel memory area starting at `PAGE_OFFSET`+896M) for its job.

So

- I think Mat's answer is suitable for pages in `ZONE_NORMAL`
- Suppose we use `kmap()` to find the starting physical address of the 4KB data associated with the struct page, is it correct that we should use `(unsigned long)(&page)-PAGE_OFFSET` to find the physical address where stores the structure itself?

Please correct.

Comment: Think about `page` as an item in the `mem_map` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map a `page` into the kernel memory as follows:

```
void * mapping = kmap_atomic(page, KM_USER0);
// work with mapping...
kunmap_atomic(mapping, KM_USER0);
```

This trick is required as there is a `HighMemory` concept in Linux (see [this](http://lwn.net/Articles/75174/) link for ex.).

UPD: You can use `kmap` instead of `kmap_atomic` in non-atomic contexts.

Comment: The OP says he already has a `struct page`, why should he need to map it exactly? (BTW: http://lwn.net/Articles/356378/; that second argument to kmap_atomic went away some time in 2009 afaict)

Comment: Well, there are some constrains when dealing with the HighMemory. Generic 32-bit kernel can see only 1G of memory (after 0xc000000). So imagine that you have more then 4G of RAM. How do you access it from the kernel?