# Read raw MMC data from eMMC disk in Linux driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

So I have a U-Boot boot loader with environment on the eMMC (i.MX6Q CPU). I would like to read the environment, starting at 0x7D000 for length 0x20000. In one of my [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64877659/how-can-i-read-mmc-partitions-in-a-linux-driver) I already found out how to list the eMMC device.

I did find out that I can make use of the `block_device_operations` in the `gendisk` struct, but my struct doesn't have the `direct_access` operation ([it's null](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.17/source/drivers/mmc/card/block.c#L588)).

I want to read the U-Boot environment not in the block device itself (if that makes sense), but in a separate driver. This is both useful knowledge as better to solve my problem.

**EDIT:**
The following code works for me.

```c
#define ADDR_TO_SECT(sect) (sect / 512)
static inline int test_mmc_read(char * pn) {
        struct block_device *dev = NULL;
        struct gendisk *disk = NULL;
        void *kaddr = NULL; // kernel address from page
        unsigned long pfn = 0; // page frame number (pfn)
        struct page *pg = NULL;
        struct bio *bio = NULL;
#define FAILME
#ifndef FAILME
        int partno = 1;
#endif
        dev_t devt = blk_lookup_devt("mmcblk0", 0);
        DECLARE_COMPLETION(setup_done);

        dev = bdget(devt);
        if (!dev) goto err;

#ifdef FAILME
        disk = part_to_disk(dev->bd_part);
#else
        disk = get_gendisk(devt, &partno);
#endif          
        if (!disk) goto err;

        if (!blkdev_get(dev, FMODE_READ | FMODE_EXCL, dev)) {
        //if (!blkdev_get(dev, FMODE_READ, NULL)) { // results in "Err blkdev_get"
                printk(KERN_ERR "Err blkdev_get\n");
                goto err;
        }
         
        pg = alloc_page(GFP_KERNEL);
        bio = bio_alloc(GFP_NOIO, 1);

        if (!bio) {
                printk(KERN_ERR "bio is null\n");
                goto err;
        }

        if (!pg) {
                printk(KERN_ERR "page is null\n");
                goto err;
        }

        bio->bi_bdev = dev;
        bio->bi_sector = ADDR_TO_SECT(0x7D000);
        bio->bi_private = &setup_done; //kmalloc(sizeof(struct completion), GFP_KERNEL);
        bio->bi_end_io = &cp15c15_mmc_init_end_io;

        bio_add_page(bio, pg, PAGE_SIZE, 0);

        init_completion(bio->bi_private);
        submit_bio(READ | REQ_SYNC, bio);
        
        wait_for_completion(bio->bi_private);
        pfn = __page_to_pfn(pg);
        printk(KERN_ERR "bi_vcnt:%d, bi_idx:%d, pfn=%lu\n", bio->bi_vcnt, bio->bi_idx, pfn);
        
        kaddr = kmap(pg);
        printk(KERN_ERR "%p:ouput = %s\n", kaddr, (char *)kaddr);

        kunmap(pg);

        return 0;
err:
        printk(KERN_ERR "Could not locate mmcblk0");
        return -1;
}
```

Since the help of TrendP I'm able to read from the block device:

```
[   26.994744] bi_vcnt:1, bi_idx:1, pfn=140824
[   26.998942] 92618000:ouput = c�N�baseargs=setenv bootargs console=${console},${baudrate}
```

---

URL:

[accessing-block-device-in-kernel-space](https://fp-instruments.com/en/accessing-block-device-in-kernel-space/) 
[how-to-get-the-physical-address-of-the-associated-data-from-a-struct-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007571/how-to-get-the-physical-address-of-the-associated-data-from-a-struct-page)

Comment: Normally reading and writing the u-boot env from Linux would be done from userspace, not in the kernel.

Comment: That I understand, but I would like to know more about the Linux kernel API :-) In userspace I already know about fw_printenv.

Comment: Take a look at https://fp-instruments.com/en/accessing-block-device-in-kernel-space/  But part of the reason this is hard, is because you aren't supposed to do this in kernel space, so there isn't a good API for it.  If you want to pass info from u-boot to the kernel, consider using a u-boot device-tree fixup to add it to the dt.  This is done for the kernel command line, serial console baud rate, and sometimes an ethernet mac address.  This is much easier to access in the kernel.

Comment: @TrentP: I got it. If you leave an answer I will accept it. Thanks man!